# mLab authentication fails via heroku using Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, heroku

I have used following document to add mLab to my Java Spring-PrimeFaces app

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab

I am creating mongoTemplate using spring configuration like this

```
<mongo:db-factory host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}"
                  dbname="${mongo.dbname}" username="${mongo.user}" password="${mongo.pass}"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>
```

the `${mongo.*}` properties are set in different file. It is working fine on local mongodb installation. However, when i replace it with the values that I received by executing command `heroku config | grep MONGODB_URI`, I am getting error that authentication failed

```
2016-06-12T17:48:14.475927+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [heroku_x2xxx5xx], username = [heroku_x2xxx5xx], password = [6************************a]
2016-06-12T17:48:14.475914+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
2016-06-12T17:48:14.475919+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
2016-06-12T17:48:14.450178+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 23 more
2016-06-12T17:48:14.475910+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
```

However, when i try to connect via console on my local machine, it works fine

```
~ $: mongo ds013564.mlab.com:13564/heroku_x2xxx5xx -u heroku_x2xxx5xx -p 6************************a
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: ds013564.mlab.com:13564/heroku_x2xxx5xx
rs-ds013564:PRIMARY> db
heroku_x2xxx5xx
```

Comment: Is your application able to connect to the remote (Heroku) mongo instance when you run it locally with this configuration?